# Android camera implementation which one is better

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-custom-view

I am developing a app on android in which i have to take the pic with the help of camera.I know there are two ways to do this . On is by intent and second one is by using camera object. I google and i know
that via intent some time application force close because of implementation of camera is different in each device . So many time no data is returned by the device.
For custom camera

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
```

So please tell me that which one is better approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is true that using Intent exposes you to diversity of imnplementations. But unfortunately same happens for use of Camera class to build "custom camera". Here fragmentation may also cause lots of problems, most of which are "hidden" from you when you use the Intent approach.

If you want to go this route, I suggest that you build on top of existing frameworks, e.g. [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) by [Mark Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).